# Jquery Refreshing Div only once

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I use jquery/ajax and php for active/deactive status, it works like when user clicks on active to turns into deactive and vice versa i'm able run this but ever time i click on active and deactive button it loads entire div section continuously.

my requirement is after click on active/deactive status the div should load only once and should stop recursively blinking for 2 to three times!

```
while($row = $data->fetch_arry(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{ ?>
    <div>
        <?php if($row['status'] == '1'){?>
        <a class='btn btn-success active'></a>
        <?php else if($row['status'] == '0')?>
        <a class='btn btn-danger deactive'></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Jquery Code

```
$('body').delegate('.active','click',function(e){
    var IDstatus = 0;
    $.post('status.php',{
        status:IDstatus
    },function(e){
        $('#div_load').load('#div_load');
    })
})

$('body').delegate('.deactive','click',function(e){
    var IDstatus = 1;
    $.post('status.php',{
        status:IDstatus
    },function(e){
        $('#div_load').load('#div_load');
    })
})
```

I want only my **#div_load** should refresh once after changing my status!

Any help is appreciated Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to `load` element on itself which is quite not valid. `load` should be used to load external file element and its kind of `ajax`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thanks!! I changed it ('#div_load').load('demo.php'); still its loading/blinking

Comment: Try using `$.when` and `.done` with `$.post` and write your `$.load` in `.done`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thank you your suggestion was helpful Thanks!!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following

```
$(document).rady(function(){
$(".active").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "status.php",
    data:{status:1},
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(result){
         $('#div_load').html(result);
    }
    });
});$(".deactive").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "status.php",
    data:{status:0},
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(result){
         $('#div_load').html(result);
    }
    });
});
```

});

Don't use load()... it is like ajax. just pass the data from the server which you want to load inside the div

Comment: Thank you for your code..I used ur code it works fin but i get updated successfully html msg it would ve been good after updating it remains in same page Any help Appreciated Thanks!

Comment: i would like to help. but i am unable to understand what you are trying to tell. can you edit your post and update your current script.